# Count days of week to detect missing days

Tags: ms-access

I've created an expression 
`=WeekDay([ApptDate]))` and then used it as a group in a report. Sometimes all days of a week show up, and sometimes only five, or six days, in the footer for this group.

```
Day         Appts
Monday      10
Tuesday     16
Thursday     5
Saturday     9
Totals: 4   40
```

It is easy to get the sum of appts (40), but I need to have a count of days that appear in this footer section to make it easy to spot when days are missing.

Comment: Maybe: Count(*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate table containing the weekday names and a sort order (i.e. Monday=1, Sunday=7) and then create a join with that table to always return all day names and the count.

Unfortunately I can't include screen shots at the moment (I'll try and add this evening when I get home).

```
SELECT      tbl_WeekDays.DayName
            , COUNT(WeekDay(ApptDate)) AS Appts
FROM        tbl_WeekDays LEFT JOIN DateTable ON tbl_WeekDays.DayName=WEEKDAYNAME(WeekDay(DateTable.ApptDate))
GROUP BY    tbl_WeekDays.DayName, tbl_WeekDays.SortOrder
ORDER BY    tbl_WeekDays.SortOrder
```

With the `tbl_WeekDays` table on the left of the LEFT join all records from that table will be returned.

I've also fully qualified each field name with the table name although you don't need to do this if the name isn't ambiguous.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to have a field to join it with in my appt table?

Comment: You'd join it on the date `tbl_WeekDays.DayName=WEEKDAYNAME(WeekDay(DateTable.ApptDate))`

Comment: this table and join should be added to the select statement for the report's record source?  It will be a really long query.... so just confirming.

Comment: Yes, you'd create the table with seven records and join it to the table containing your dates.  Hard to say exactly where as I can't see the rest of the SQL and don't know the structure of the tables in it.  Might be easier to go with @Gustavs answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have seven stacked textboxes, one for each weekday, with these ControlSources:

```
=Abs(Sum(1=Weekday[ApptDate])))
=Abs(Sum(2=Weekday[ApptDate])))
...
=Abs(Sum(7=Weekday[ApptDate])))
```